# Sharing views between BigQuery projects

Tags: view, google-bigquery

I am using Google BigQuery to analyze data for several clients with same algorithms . All projects have same Location. Those algorithms are views.

Is it possible to have those views at only one project, and run it over different project data?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes. While view is in one project - data/tables referenced in it can reside in another project.

Btw, using this "model" you can "separate" users from having access to actual data by giving them access to View ONLY, while sharing respective dataset with this View using "Authorized View" option

> I don't want to create views for every project, but run the view over
>   different projects without any change

Generically speaking, as of today, this is not possible!
Till when Views will support passing parameters/arguments or something like this

Still, I see one option for below particular case!

If you have exactly same logic and data schema and only what is different for different clients is project - you should use something like below (just an idea to explore)

```
SELECT * FROM 
  (SELECT * FROM [projectA:dataset.table] WHERE CURRENT_USER() IN ('name1@clientA.com', 'name2@clientA.com')),
  (SELECT * FROM [projectB:dataset.table] WHERE CURRENT_USER() IN ('name1@clientB.com', 'name2@clientB.com')),
  (SELECT * FROM [projectC:dataset.table] WHERE CURRENT_USER() IN ('name1@clientC.com', 'name2@clientC.com'))
```

So, depends on which user is running View - respective data will be served.
Of course in this case  - using Authorized View as option for Sharing Data is a MUST, so clientA has no any access to ClientB or ClientC data

Above example can be modified to below

```
SELECT * FROM 
  (SELECT *, 'ClientA' AS client FROM [projectA:dataset.table]),
  (SELECT *, 'ClientB' AS client FROM [projectB:dataset.table]),
  (SELECT *, 'ClientC' AS client FROM [projectC:dataset.table])
```

so the view can be used as below

```
SELECT * FRIN YourView WHERE client = 'ClientB'
```

> IMPORTANT

Please have in mind that above abstract/theoretical options will lead you to be charged for querying ALL involved projects each and every time you run it. even though you will get result only related to specific project/client.
I dont think you want this to happen

Comment: Thanks Mikhail. Is it a way like "use project-name"? I mean, I don't want to create views for every project, but run the view over different projects without any change.